# Website development using Signalr Asp.Net

Tags: signalr

I want to develop website ( aspx Page ) using Signalr technology. ( not MVC architecture )

can anybody help me out how to interact the db with Signalr. ( like Edit, update, delete )

Thanks.!

Answer (score 1):

SignalR is used for real time communication between client and server.  As for communicating with a database, that's no different than in any other asp.net application.

You can utilize SignalR to have a client call into a server method which then in turn communicates with a database but I'd be weary of that approach due to security concerns.

Comment: i have searched a lot, i found the same results like chat app using signalr & stock app using html page.  I wanna start with aspx page not MVC architechture. that too i wanna interact with database using signalr tech. how can we do this? for example i have a screen which used to add, update, delete some data. this operations should be real time. I wanna achieve this using signalr. This involves database connectivity. how can we handle this.

Comment: Database connectivity is not SignalR's responsibility.  As I said in my answer, SignalR is only for client to server real time communication.

Comment: yes Mr.Taylor i understood somewhat. Is it possible to create a real time app ( In my case I have a screen with textbox and add button. Once i entered text and click add, the added value will be display on the below grid. now many users are seeing the same page. This changes should reflect all the users who currently visiting the page without refresh the page.) using this signalr & 3-tier asp.net application?

Comment: thank you for your response taylor.! expecting some more input on this query.

Comment: Of course that's possible, SignalR allows you to send messages down to all clients in real time.  If you then want to include a database in your design all you have to do is make one of your SignalR server side methods communicate with a database.  AKA your Add button would trigger JavaScript which would in turn call the server (via SignalR) which the server would then add X row to your database.

Comment: thanks taylor. i have done this by calling WCF service through JQuery.